# What is "Trace/BPT trap: 5"?

Tags: macos, crash, error-code

What does *Trace/BPT trap: 5* mean, when a Mac OS X application suddenly exits?

Searching the web I only found out that a lot of applications exit like this (ruby, postgres) but only find application specific solution. But I want to understand what that is and how it is caused.

I also found that it seems to be an issue on Mac OS X only (did not find any mentions of this happening with Linux or Windows). I believe it has something to do with threading, but I'm not sure about that one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It has to do with not being able to find/load a `dylib`, which is specific to OSX.
Which one it can't find, is as you have found out is application specific.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to find which `dylib` it can't find/load?