# Trying to do a simple git init and I am getting Trace/BPT trap: 5

Tags: git

Hoping someone can help me with this. Learning GIT. I am on `iMac version 10.8.5`. I am simply trying to set up a git init repository from `cd Documents/first_git_project` and it keeps returning `No such file or directory or a Trace/BPT trap: 5 error`.

If anyone could help that would be great.

Basically I set up a folder in my Documents folder called `first_git_project`. Trying to use the terminal to set up a `git init` and create a repository.

Here is where the terminal says it is located; /usr/local/git/bin/git

Comment: From where did you install `git`?

Comment: Is this thread useful to you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14675206/mac-os-x-what-is-trace-bpt-trap-5

Comment: Here is where it is installed per my terminal: /usr/local/git/bin/git

Comment: Perhaps this can be of use to you: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/6891